# Rust ndarray - Randomly fill ndarray wish shape I specify

Tags: rust

I need to make a 2d array with the shape I specify and have it randomly filled.

I tried the code below, but it yells at me

```rust
pub fn fill_shape(x:i32 , y:i32){
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut a = vec![];
    for x in 0..(x*y)
    {
        a.push(rng.gen_range(0.0..1.0));
    }
    let mut temp = ndarray::Array::from_shape_vec((x, y),a);
}
```

[this is why it gets upset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm59Y.png)

it works when i do something like (2,2)
error message

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(i32, i32): Dimension` is not satisfied
  --> src\mynn.rs:42:20
   |
42 |     let mut temp = ndarray::Array::from_shape_vec((x, y),a);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Dimension` is not implemented for `(i32, i32)`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `From<(i32, i32)>` for `StrideShape<(i32, i32)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<StrideShape<(i32, i32)>>` for `(i32, i32)`
   = note: required by `ndarray::impl_constructors::<impl ArrayBase<S, D>>::from_shape_vec`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the error message.

Comment: added the error message,@SakuraKinomoto

Comment: I've see it, thanks for doing it. I'm not an expert of rust, I've recommended you to post the error for someone with better knowledge can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types that can be converted into `Dimension`s and therefore used as parameters expecting `Into<StrideShape>` are limited to `Ix`s which is an alias for `usize`. See [`IntoDimension`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.3/ndarray/trait.IntoDimension.html):

Either convert `x` and `y` to `usize`:

```
ndarray::Array::from_shape_vec((x as usize, y as usize), a)
```

Or if appropriate, change them for your `fill_shape` function:

```
pub fn fill_shape(x: usize, y: usize) {
```